# Can ARKit (or ARSession) keep running in the background?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, wkwebview, arkit

My question is - Can `ARSession` run in the background - basically I need the ARKit running and all the per frame information and camera incentrics but I DONT want to render the camera feed on the screen - As happens in the `ARSCNView`.

Not specifically in the background thread or process.

Basically I just want to use the Tracking information(Images + Camera Pos + Camera Euler Angles etc) from the ARKit and dont want to render anything in AR per se or the camera feed.

Before everyone jumps on me - I know that Apple restricts GPU process in the background - case in point :

> Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during
>   execution. Insufficient Permission (to submit GPU work from
>   background) (IOAF code 6)

But there should be a way to use the `ARKit` or `ARSession` without the camera feed and only with the tracking information, right?

Comment: If there isn't a background mode for it, you can't do it in the background

Comment: Do you mean in the background of the os all the time, or just in the background while your app is running?

Comment: @JulianMinde Just while the app is running. Pretty sure Apple wont allow it to run any process in the background which hogs the GPU.

Comment: @Scriptable So in order to use the tracking information - I need to render the camera feed on the app view/screen. Seems a bit restrictive.

Comment: When your app enters the background, your app has a limited time to do some last minute processing/update db's/make a network call or whatever, after a short time the app will be suspended and then these processes (if still running) will be stopped.  So you cannot run an AR process at all after this time, whether it is to the screen or not

Comment: @Scriptable I understand that. I want to ARKit to run while my app is running on foreground. I want the camera frame information and camera pos but I want to send this information over to my js app running  WKWebview in the app.

Comment: ok... you can probably do all that stuff in the foreground, but not in the background

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you want to do, as soon as the `ARSCNScene` or `ARSKScene` is fully covered AR tracking stops. There are a couple reasons for this.

First, ARKit is for Augmented Reality, not tracking operations. If you aren't displaying reality (the camera feed) on the screen then you cannot augment reality.

Second, and most important, Apple cares about user privacy and if you could access the camera without showing the feed onscreen the user would have no way of knowing when the camera was in use. This would leave open the possibility of apps spying on users without their knowledge. Apple will never allow this. Ever.

Also, AR hits the battery hard so it only runs when its actually being used.

Based on your comments it seems as though you don't actually want to create an AR experience anyway so there may be a better way to get what you are after through Heading information and the Accelerometer.